# Change site when editing question in Android app?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, android-app

I went to edit a question and saw it was possible to modify the site that the question was asked on. Knowing that this was impossible, I attempted to "move" my question from Meta Stack Overflow to Stack Overflow. On submit, I got a cryptic error message "only questions can be edited with this method". I'm assuming the message is directly from the API since you can't move the question that easily.

So can the site picker become a text label when editing a question? Or if it's decided that is [poor UI design](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/07/01.html), can the error message be worded better allowing users to understand what they did wrong?

[image: screenshot]  [image: error message]

Comment: Great catch, it's not a case of the error being *wrong* per-say, just the API getting confused when we try to do this. I'll disable the drop-down and make it text-only when editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in version 0.1.41, thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... in v0.1.40 the app force closes when I tap on the time stamp of this question from within the app. Should I make a new post for that?

Comment: I see the crash in our logs, will fix :)