# When image linked to image the Android app displays it twice

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, images, android-app

On my [last question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198053/change-site-when-editing-question-in-android-app), I used markdown to link to the larger versions of the screenshots. When you tap on the image the native OS browser opens to URL. Then when I return to the app, I have a WebView waiting for me with the thumbnail/smaller version loaded from the image URL in the post.

I like the feature that enlarges the image on tap, especially when the image is being fit to the screen. But if the image is apart of a link, can the WebView not be displayed since the browser is loaded? Or present an option to follow the link, or expand the image?

<sub>Using v0.1.39 on Android 4.3</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. Version 0.1.41 makes it so that the in-app zooming functionality now only shows up for images that aren't wrapped in anchor tags.

Comment: I must be [raining on the 0.1.40 parade](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198053/change-site-when-editing-question-in-android-app/198163#comment627760_198163). I'm still getting the opening of the image inside the WebView when I return to the app with 0.1.40.

Comment: Oops, I've clearly not had enough coffee today, wrong version number!

Comment: (assuming you're in NY) Not enough coffee by 3pm? That's a long day...

Comment: I'm clearly not taking advantage of our [latte machine with complementary training from Joel Spolsky](https://twitter.com/StackExchange/status/333949666796371970)