# Open linked images in comments within the android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Currently if someone links to an image linked in a comment it opens the browser to view it.

I think it should open the image within the app. Particularly if it's a stack exchange imgur link.

Comment: Possible added information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198119/when-image-linked-to-image-the-android-app-displays-it-twice